# contact form not giving data

Tags: php, forms, fat-free-framework

I have issue with fat-free contact form.
My contact form does nothing. Like no success or any kind of error data.

My contact form POST and GET route:

```
$f3->route('GET @contact: /contact', 'Rimtay\Client->GET_Contact');
$f3->route('POST @contact: /send', 'Rimtay\Client->contactPost');
```

My contact form POST function:

```
function contactPost(){

        function validateInput($data) {
            $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

            foreach ($bad as $badString) {
                if (preg_match('/('.$badString.')/i',$data)) {
                    // If it looks like someone is trying to hack
                    // into the site via the contact page, then just stop.
                    exit;
                }
            }
            return $data;
        }
        // define variables and set to empty values
        $contactNameError = $contactEmailError = $contactMessageError = "";
        $name = $email = $message = $success = "";

        if ($f3->exists('POST.name',$name)) {
            if ($name !== '') {
                $name = validateInput($name);
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                    $contactNameError = "Wrong name";
                } else { // valid name
                    $f3->set('contactName',$name);
                }
            } else {
                $contactNameError = "name empty";
            }
        } else {
            $contactNameError = "name error";
        }

        if ($f3->exists('POST.email',$email)) {
            if ($email !== '') {
                $email = validateInput($email);
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $contactEmailError = "wrong email";
                } else { // valid email
                    $f3->set('contactEmail',$email);
                }
            } else {
                $contactEmailError = "email empty";
            }
        } else {
            $contactEmailError = "error email";
        }

        if ($f3->exists('POST.subject',$message)) {
            if ($message !== '') {
                $f3->set('contactMessage',$message);
            } else {
                $contactMessageError = "message tühi";
            }
        } else {
            $contactMessageError = "lambi message";
        }


        if (($contactNameError === '') && ($contactEmailError === '') && ($contactMessageError === '')) {
            // send the message
            $messageBody = "";
            unset($_POST['submit']);
            $messageBody = "Name: ".$name."\n";
            $messageBody .= "email: ".$email."\n";
            $messageBody .= "Subject: Construction - Message from " . $name."\n";
            $messageBody .= $message."\n";
            $messageBody = wordwrap($messageBody,70);
            
            $to = $f3->get('contactAddresses');
            $subject = 'Contact Submitted';
            if (mail($to, $subject, $messageBody)){
                $f3->set('contactSuccess',true);
            } else {
                // error sending the email to myself
            }
        } else {
            $f3->set('contactSuccess',false);
        }
        
        // Set the content source
        $this->f3->set('pageContent','contact.html');
    }
```

my form looks like this:

```
<form class="form" action="{{ @schemeHost.@PATH }}" method="post">
    <textarea class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Message*">{{ @contactMessage }}</textarea>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name *" name="name" value="{{ @contactName }}" class="input">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email *" name="email" value="{{ @contactEmail }}" class="input">
    </div>
    <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

My System isnt giving any success or error messages.
And not sending out contact form messages to email.

I dont see what I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: What does your `action` attribute render out as? Just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very prone to errors. For example, the `$f3` variable is not defined anywhere in your code.

How does your code handle the errors? It might be that you see no errors because there is no error reporting setup by you and the server is silently not showing the errors. I suggest you to check the error log.

I also suggest to use a form validation library like [CakePHP validation library](https://github.com/cakephp/validation). You will need to learn how to use it, but it will save you big time in the end and your code will be cleaner.

Comment: sorry yeah it should be `$this->f3`